# Span within a Span, href link is missing

Tags: css, email, html

I am loading in a CSV content file to compile an email. There are several columns, but the end layout is like this:

```
<span style="font-family: arial, general;">Hi [First Name],<br><br>


Email body...
Please click the link below <br><a href="[Invite Link]&collector=#{collector_final_id}">Get Started</a><br><br>We appreciate your feedback and look forward to hearing from you!<br><br>

Signature name <br>
Signature Title


<br><br><br><span style="font-size:11px;”>Please <a href="[Unsubscribe Link]">click here</a> to unsubscribe</span></span>
```

The end result looks as I expect up until the last line, or the unsubscribe piece. It simply says this:

```
to unsubscribe
```

`to unsubscribe` is in the right font size (`11px`) and it is in Arial. Why does `Please click here` not show up? The hyperlink in the `Email body` shows up fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the last line, in `<span style="font-size:11px;”>`, the closing quotes are fancy-quotes rather than normal quotes. Make sure you only ever use the normal " and ' in your html. Fix that and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have a fancy end quote on the span style attribute.